# Send the request using HEAD to the BigQuery dataset collection

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

We run into strange error when trying to check existence of a dataset in BigQuery via HEAD request executed on App Engine environment. Please see the code below.

```
bigquery.datasets().get(projectNumber, datasetId).executeUsingHead();
```

That code is working successfully if run on local development server, however, when deployed on Google infrastructure, we get IOException.

```
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:148)
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:43)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchRequest.execute(UrlFetchRequest.java:79)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:980)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:399)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUsingHead(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:382)
at com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Datasets$Get.executeUsingHead(Bigquery.java:322)
...
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using execute() instead of executeUsingHead()? The datasets.get() operation only returns a single dataset object, which is generally very small.

Comment: The reason is that I only need to check if a dataset exists or not. I am not interested in any dataset details. I know that a dataset object is small but I feel it is much clearer in such cases to use HEAD. Anyway, at the moment I am using GET as a workaround, however, I am curious to know what is the cause of the above exception.